# Output name varies on different line

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, replace

I am writing down a program to write the some names in text file accoring to my 2 nd cloumn names, As you can see here https://imageshack.com/i/eyW14lH6j. My output view is shown in the link.
So what i have done is, its reading line by line text of the 2 nd column and its generating names according to the **MAX_PN column name**.

For ex: as in the above output view i need when ever a same string (100-0145 comes i need Carousel:4 to be shown)
I wanted to be like if the 2nd column names are alike i need same name to be appeared in the **Location column**. But what happening for my code is,
if a same name appears after one or two three lines it not reading. How can i rectify this. Please help me out.

My code snippet:

```
            int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15 };
            string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string line = string.Empty;
            string LastComment = string.Empty;
            string CarouselName = "Carousel";
            int iCarousel = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
            {
                line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim();
                string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');
                for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                    sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));

                if (cells.Length > 1)
                {
                    if (cells[1] != LastComment & i > 0)
                    {
                        iCarousel++;
                        if (iCarousel > 45)
                            iCarousel = 1;
                        LastComment = cells[1];
                    }

                    if (i == 0)
                        sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));
                    else
                        sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel).PadRight(15));
                }
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: So you want to read the **MAX_PN** from a text file and then assign each **MAX_PN** number a unique **Carousel:x** where **x** is a number?

Comment: @Mihai yes excatly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving all names in a Dictionary where int is the number of the carousel.
Then you can check what carousel matches your name.
look at this sample:

```
Dictionary<string,int> namesForCarousels = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

...

```
if (cells.Length > 1)
{
    var name = cells[1];
    int carouselNumber;
    if (namesForCarousels.TryGetValue(name, out carouselNumber) == false)
        {
            carouselNumber = iCarousel++;
            namesForCarousels[name] = carouselNumber;
        }
    if (i == 0)
    sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));
    else
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, carouselNumber).PadRight(15));
}
```

Comment: showing error .. `Error The name 'namesForCarousels' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: can you please have a loo to my question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723495/how-to-programatically-convert-the-text-file-to-a-custom-made-specific-excel-for/26725180#26725180>