# How to programatically convert the text file to a custom made specific excel format with nice tabulated grid

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, grouping

I would like to convert my text file https://imageshack.com/i/eyRUOp6fj to a specific **excel format** as shown here https://imageshack.com/i/iqVnLA9vj. How can i do this.

In the text file, there are number of components which **has same location name**. So basically I want to **cluster all components with same location name to one row**, with total number of components in the 2nd column and so on. Please guide me how can i do this.

Code Snippet:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\bleh\testdata.txt");
 List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>(lines.Length);
 Dictionary<string, List<Item>> itemsByLocation = new Dictionary<string, List<Item>>   (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
// loop the file, start at 1 assuming headings first row
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
// nothing interesting here, just parsing the file
string[] columns = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ';', ',' });                
Item item = new Item() { 
    Designator = columns[ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR], 
    MaxPn = columns[ORDINAL_MAXPN], 
    Footprint = columns[ORDINAL_FOOTPRINT], 
    Location = columns[ORDINAL_LOCATION] };

allItems.Add(item);
List<Item> itemsForThisKey = null;
if (itemsByLocation.TryGetValue(item.Location, out itemsForThisKey) == false)
{
    // we don't already have this location in the dictionary, add it
    itemsForThisKey = new List<Item>();
    itemsByLocation.Add(item.Location, itemsForThisKey);
}
itemsForThisKey.Add(item); // add this item to the relevant grouping
```

}

I am getting error in Item `Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
Also, error for `Error  7   The name 'ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR' does not exist in the current context` Any helps please!!!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried to do already? You're supposed to show us the effort you've put towards fixing the problem.

Comment: @furkle i just need a suggestion from where i can start it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [pastie](http://pastie.org/9694762) of your full code

Create a class to store the particular row of excel sheet. Then assign the data in the loop.

```
public class ExcelData
{
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<string> Designator { get; set; }
    public string Comment  { get; set; }
    public string Footprint  { get; set; }
    public string Location  { get; set; }

    public ExcelData()
    {
        Designator = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

And add the following code in the loop to generate excel data.

```
List<ExcelData> lstExcel = new List<ExcelData>();
ExcelData fline = null;
for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
{
    line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim();
    if (line.Length == 0)
        continue;
    string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\t');

    if (i > 0)
    {
        if (cells[1] != LastComment)
        {
            if (fline != null)
                lstExcel.Add(fline);
            fline = new ExcelData();
            fline.SrNo++;
            fline.Footprint = cells[2].Replace(" ", "_");
            fline.Comment = cells[1].Replace(" ", "_");


            iCarousel++;
            if (iCarousel > 45)
                iCarousel = 1;
            LastComment = cells[1];
            fline.Location = String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel);
        }

        fline.Designator.Add(cells[0].Replace(" ", "_"));                        
        fline.Total++;
    }
}
ExportInExcel(lstExcel, @"D:\myExcel.xls");
```

Also create a new function that exports the data into excel file.

**NOTE: to use this method you have to add reference for Microsoft Excel Object Library. `Project->Add Reference->COM->Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library`**

```
private void ExportInExcel(List<ExcelData> lstData, string excelPath)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sr No.";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Total";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Designator";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Comment";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Footprint";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Location";

    for (int i = 0; i < lstData.Count; i++)
    {
        //i+2 : in Excel file row index is starting from 1. It's not a 0 index based collection
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 1] = (i + 1).ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 2] = lstData[i].Total.ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 3] = String.Join(",",lstData[i].Designator.ToArray());
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 4] = lstData[i].Comment;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 5] = lstData[i].Footprint;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, 6] = lstData[i].Location;

    }

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(excelPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
}

//This function is created to release the excel class object.
private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But shell the output excel is generating excel sheet. But the file is having only header column names.. No data inside..

Comment: yes i tried.. in that it showing instance null error for ` fline.Comment = cells[1].Replace(" ", "_");`

Comment: Yes.. now it perfect.. but alignment is not correct

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is really about how to do the grouping and not about how to read the file and output to Excel. I guess the data structure of choice for grouping would be a dictionary, so your key in this case would be "Location", and you put all matching items against that key to create a grouping.

Alternatively, you could also use linq - below has both ways.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\bleh\testdata.txt");
List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>(lines.Length);
Dictionary<string, List<Item>> itemsByLocation = new Dictionary<string, List<Item>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
// loop the file, start at 1 assuming headings first row
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    // nothing interesting here, just parsing the file
    string[] columns = lines[i].Split(new char[] { '\t' });                
    Item item = new Item() { 
        Designator = columns[ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR], 
        MaxPn = columns[ORDINAL_MAXPN], 
        Footprint = columns[ORDINAL_FOOTPRINT], 
        Location = columns[ORDINAL_LOCATION] };

    allItems.Add(item);
    List<Item> itemsForThisKey = null;
    if (itemsByLocation.TryGetValue(item.Location, out itemsForThisKey) == false)
    {
        // we don't already have this location in the dictionary, add it
        itemsForThisKey = new List<Item>();
        itemsByLocation.Add(item.Location, itemsForThisKey);
    }
    itemsForThisKey.Add(item); // add this item to the relevant grouping
}

// obligatory answer in linq
var itemsByLocationWithLinq = from singleItem in allItems
                    group singleItem by singleItem.Location into groupedItems
                    select new { Location = groupedItems.Key, Items = groupedItems.ToList() };

// now you have your groups so you can do with them as you will
foreach (var itemLocation in itemsByLocationWithLinq)            
    Console.WriteLine("Linq: {0} has {1:#,0} items", itemLocation.Location, itemLocation.Items.Count);

foreach (var itemLocation in itemsByLocation.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary: {0} has {1:#,0} items", itemLocation, itemsByLocation[itemLocation].Count);
```

Update, the item is a simple holder for row data to make it easier to work with, and the ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR are just constants referring to the column's position in the text file. They can be defined as below in an appropriate scope to get the snippet to compile.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Designator { get; set; }
    public string MaxPn { get; set; }
    public string Footprint { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

private const int ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR = 0;
private const int ORDINAL_MAXPN = 1;
private const int ORDINAL_FOOTPRINT = 2;
private const int ORDINAL_LOCATION = 5;
```

Comment: `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `Error 7 The name 'ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It was just a snippet not a whole program :) ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR are just constants, you can define them (the column numbers from your text file, so zero for ORDINAL_DESIGNATOR, 1 for ORDINAL_MAXPN etc). Item is a simple class to hold the data, just define a class with those properties. I will add it for completeness to the example

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking. If you want to create an Excel file then I'd recommend one of the following options:

1) Use a **third party component** to write an Excel file. I've used Aspose Cells see  http://www.aspose.com/

2) **Automate Microsoft's Excel** using C# see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

3) Use **ADO and Jet**    see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973

Comment: Are people still automating Excel? I thought everyone was using the  Open Office XML SDK these days :o)

Comment: Well I admit I haven't done it for a loooong time! There's always some new fangled way of doing things :)